# C++ deleting pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, int, concatenation

I have a program that contains a doctor class, and each Doctor object has a linked list of "Patients".  These patients are created using the following line of code

```
Patient * patient = new Patient(string firstname, string ailment);
```

And this patient is then added to a Doctor's linked list.
There is a pointer in the Doctor class that is used to point to and iterate through the list and get each patient.  When I want to delete these patients, I have to start at the beginning of my list and iterate through each one. My question is, can I delete eacg patient by simply calling their destructors as I iterate through them?

```
Patient::~Patient(){

}
```

or do I need to actually call delete on the pointer as it points each employee?

Comment: Do you mean, `Patient *patient = new Patient(string firstname, string ailment);`?

Comment: @slugonamission:  You can call destructors directly.

Comment: It depends how your linked list is implemented. If each Patient class stores a pointer to the next Patient, then before you call delete on each Patient, you need to get a pointer to the next one

Comment: In general you should not call destructors, you should use the delete keyword to deallocate the pointers. Just iterate through calling delete on each patient, and delete the linked list in your Doctor destructor.

Comment: @BenjaminDangerJohnson:  What garbage collector?

Comment: Looks like someone from the C# tag stumbled into C++ again :)

Comment: ah my mistake, I'll edit my comment. I'm still learning the ins and outs myself.

Comment: @slugonamission:  In C++, *you* are the garbage collector.

Comment: @JohnDibling - oops. I was under the impression you couldn't.

Comment: @slugonamission: `patient->~Patient()`

Comment: @FredLarson: I think the OP even means `Patient *patient = new Patient(firstName, ailment);`.

Comment: @LucTouraille: You're right! I got so focused on one error that I missed another.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You call `delete` to delete things.  `delete` will, in turn, result in the object's destructor being called.

Calling the destructor of a class directly is supported by C++, and is in fact useful in some rare scenarios, but it does not actually deallocate the memory.  This is not what you want to do here.

Answer (score 5):

First, `new` returns a pointer, so I guess you mean `Patient* patient = ...`.

That aside, yes, you'll need to call `delete` on everything you allocate with `new` and the destructor will be called.

**OR** (drumroll) use a `std::unique_ptr` instead.  And I hope when you say you have a list of patients, you mean you have a `std::list` of patients.

Answer (score 2):

calling `delete` will actually call the destructor for the object.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are dynamically allocating the memory for each Patient object (should be `Patient* patient` tho...) you need to manually deallocate each one as well...

Check out this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_%28C++%29#Releasing_dynamically_allocated_memory) page for more info.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you have to call delete on each pointer individually. Deleting a pointer to Patient from within the Patient destructor seems to violate the purpose of using classes (i.e. they are self contained and don't have access to the outside world).